What causes the Brompton shifter to "click" between gears?
What is the mechanism that causes the shifter in a pre-2017 M6R Brompton to "click" between the two gear positions?
I have a 2015 Brompton M6R. I was touring on this bike when I hit a pot hole. I got thrown off the saddle and the (fully loaded) bike dropped to the ground. When I picked-up the bike (and pushed it to the shoulder), I realized that the front plate on the (right-hand/American) two-speed cassette shifter fell-off. I found the plastic cover for the shifter and its bolt in the road. I bolted the plate back-on.








Figure DR24 shows the pre-2017 Brompton 2-speed shifter with the plastic front plate removed



Unfortunately, the shifter no longer "clicks" between the two gear positions. If I push the shifting lever to the right, then the chain will get pushed up onto the inner-most/large sprocket. But when I let-go, the lever naturally falls back to the left, and the chain shifts down to the outer-most/small sprocket.
I'm trying to figure-out if some component that's responsible for the "clicking" between the gears fell-off.
What is the component that's responsible for the Brompton 2-speed shifter to "click" when  changing between the two gears?

If you go directly to brompton they will help you. These shifters are crap but at least brompton look after their users.

@Noise I would have to travel a few thousand kilometers and cross at least two countries' borders to get to a Brompton shop. And that wouldn't help others. The benefit of posting on Stack Exchange is that it makes the information easier to find for others.

email or call. The help is very good. Post your result as the answer.

I would guess that when you reassembled the parts, something was missing.   A Detent requires three things, a recess, a hook, and a spring/pressure.  There's a chance some other part fell out and was lost.
